# In Spring boot application is @Component annotation optional for repo

Tags: spring-boot, annotations

I have created the basic application using Spring boot using JPA. I have added @AutoWired annotation for RatingRepo in RatingResource, but haven't added @Component annotation to RatingRepo

```html
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.demo.RatingsRateService.model.Rating;
import com.example.demo.RatingsRateService.model.UserRating;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("ratingsdata")
public class RatingResource {
 @Autowired
 RatingRepo repo;
 /*
  * @RequestMapping("/{movieId}") public Rating
  * getRating(@PathVariable("movieId") String movieId) { return new
  * Rating(movieId,7); }
  */
 
 @RequestMapping("users/{userid}")
 public UserRating getRating(@PathVariable("userid") int userid) {
  List<Rating> ratings =repo.findByUserId(userid);
  /*
   * List<Rating> ratings = Arrays.asList(new Rating("1",4), new Rating("2",3),
   * new Rating("3",2));
   */
  System.out.println(ratings);
  UserRating userRating = new UserRating();
  userRating.setUserRating(ratings);
  return userRating;
 }
}
```

```html
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

import com.example.demo.RatingsRateService.model.Rating;


//to update the data in database , created the interd=face and will implement
//class,primary key
public interface RatingRepo extends JpaRepository<Rating, Integer>{
 
 
 @Query(" from Rating  where userid = ?1")
 List<Rating>  findByUserId( int userid);
 
}
```

. Still, it is working fine. Can you someone please explain why it is so? Or it is not needed to add @Component annotation for the repo?

Answer (score 1):

**first of there is @Repository annotation required not @Component**

**and @Repository also auto configure due to below:**

Probably you are using spring boot

Spring Data repositories usually extend from the Repository or CrudRepository interfaces. If you are using auto-configuration, repositories will be searched from the package containing your main configuration class (the one annotated with @EnableAutoConfiguration or @SpringBootApplication) down.

ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-spring-data-jpa-repositories